# Uber to restaurant invoices

Tags: uber-api

Underneath the reporting endpoints we have the following as seen on https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/v1/post-eats-report:

PAYMENT_DETAILS_REPORT
ORDER_ERRORS_MENU_ITEM_REPORT
ORDER_ERRORS_TRANSACTION_REPORT
ORDER_HISTORY_REPORT
DOWNTIME_REPORT
CUSTOMER_AND_DELIVERY_FEEDBACK_REPORT
MENU_ITEM_FEEDBACK_REPORT
ORDERS_AND_ITEMS_REPORT
FINANCE_SUMMARY_REPORT

Does one of Them includes the weekly invoices sent from Uber to the restaurant?

If yes how can I get that bearer .. how could the restaurant generate a retractable token.

Kind regards,
Wouter

Comment: I would consider referencing the Uber-api docs

Comment: Thank you for helping me elaborate beter questions Orion.